# Return anonymous type inside Where method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know that to return an anonymous type I can do this:

```
var test  = from c in list
            where c.SomeField > 200
            select new { c.SomeField, c.AnotherField };
```

And that's ok.

Now, I'd like to now how to return this anonymous type doing the same thing but using the Where method.
Something like:

```
var test = list.Where((SomeType c) => { if (c.SomeField > 200) 
                                        return new { c.SomeField, c.AnotherField } });
```

Is there any way of doing it using the Where method?

Thank you!

Comment: `Where(x => x.SomeField > 200).Select(x => new { SF = x.SomeField, AF = x.AnotherField});`

Comment: Returning an anonymous type? Not sure that's the best idea. How do you plan on accessing it on the calling end? `dynamic`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Where` is not designed for this. `Where` expects a delegate that takes an *object* and returns a `bool`. So, returning an anonymous type in `Where` is not possible and doesn't make sense.

You can only filter your items with `Where` and then do the projection with `Select`

```
var test = list.Where(c=> c.SomeField > 200)
               .Select(c => new { c.SomeField, c.AnotherField });
```

Btw this is equivelant of your first query since it will be translated into this.

---

Alternatively, if you are working with `List<T>`, you can use [`List<T>.FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get all the items that matches with your predicate.